# Is it possible to pass a space character to a cgi?

Tags: http, cgi, lighttpd

I have a compiled c binary (setch) which takes the parameters `HIGH/LOW/OFF` so I am trying to execute the command eg `setch OFF` from javascript/jquery thus:

```
$.get("cgi-bin/setch.cgi","OFF"); -or  
$.get("cgi-bin/setch OFF");
```

As it's a get then the space is encoded into %20, of course. However the server then tries to execute the command `setch%20OFF` and returns:

> 404 Not Found

Without the parameter the program executes and returns my message:

> no parameters

ie all paths, permissions etc are OK

Am I trying to do the impossible here? Or am I missing something in the server (lighttpd) config?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass a parameter to a CGI. The way to do that is not to separate them with a space, instead you want to put the parameter behind a "?" character. The HTTP server will then store everything that follows behind the question mark in the QUERY_STRING environment variable that your CGI can then read.

I.e.

```
$.get("cgi-bin/setch?OFF");
```

In your C program use `getenv("QUERY_STRING")` to access the passed parameter.

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface for a list of all environment variables that the HTTP server set for CGI programs. Be sure to treat the values as untrusted data.

Comment: Thanks very much. The crucial bit I had been unable to find was the use of environment variables. All good now...